# Admob: interstitial ad never ready

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I am writing my first Admob code in swift for iOS.  I never get the test ad loaded.  Here is my very simple code in GameViewController.swift.

```
var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID, "542C7C80-AEC2-464F-B673-D005953E9307"]
    interstitial.load(request)

    sleep(10)

    if interstitial.isReady{
      interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }
    else{
      print("Ad not ready")
    }
```

Would be nice to give me a hint.

Comment: Try moving the if statement to another function to allow time for the ad to load. You are calling it immediately and that may be why it's not loading. Just set up a button and try pressing it a few seconds after opening the app

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `sleep(x)`! Anyways, use `delegates` for you to be notified whenever the ad gets ready to be presented. Like so:

```
// MARK: - GADInterstitialDelegate

extension ViewController: GADInterstitialDelegate {
    func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        ad.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set your `interstitial` instance's delegate:

`self.interstitial.delegate = self`